# Problem with cors between backend and frontend

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with my cors policy between my backend (API Rest in .NET Core 6) and my frontend (in ReactJS), the thing is that in my backend I have the following configuration:

In `appsetings.json`:

```
"AllowedHosts": "mywebsite.com"
```

In `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "mycors", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("mywebsite.com")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
app.UseCors("mycors");
```

This configuration doesn't work when I'm trying to fetch a post request to my API, but if I change the `AllowedHosts` to `"AllowedHosts": "*"` it works. I don't understand why I can't allow just to my frontend website.

Additional information, my post request has these parameters:

```
method: 'POST'
mode: 'cors',
cache: 'no-cache',
credentials: 'same-origin',
redirect: 'follow',
referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: //My parameters
```

The console error is:

> Access to fetch at 'mybackendpostmethod' from origin 'myfronturl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: What is the failure message in the browser console. It's not very interesting, for cors, to see the post request headers. It's more interesting to see the headers of the *response* to the OPTIONS request

Comment: Show the request/response to the OPTIONS. Edit the question; do not add it as a comment

Answer (score -2):

I solved putting my api that return as follows

[image]

Comment: Hi, first of all. Please **do not** post images instead of code. Please consider adding more details as to how this helps solve the question. The more detail you can add the more helpful your answer will be to other's. Please consider reviewing the how to answer article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer